# Checkbox EventHandler not changing text in label (JavaFX)

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, eventhandler

I'm just learning Java, things have been going well thus far. I am learning the basics of JavaFX and wrote a program that just shows some Checkboxes controls and Labels. I am trying to get the Label called response to change text when a user clicks on one(or any) of the checkbox. The code below shows only EventHandler for bananaCB checkbox.

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler {
private Label title;
private Label response;
private Label selected;
private CheckBox bananaCB;
private CheckBox mangoCB;
private CheckBox papayaCB;
private CheckBox grapfruitCB;
private String fruits;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    primaryStage.setTitle("Favorite Fruit");

    title = new Label("What fruits do you like?");
    response = new Label("");
    selected = new Label("");

    bananaCB = new CheckBox("Banana");
    mangoCB = new CheckBox("Mango");
    papayaCB = new CheckBox("Papaya");
    grapfruitCB = new CheckBox("Grapfruit");


    //Setup the stage and Scene
    FlowPane flowPaneRoot = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL,5,5);
    flowPaneRoot.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    //We add all of our controls to flowPaneRoot
    flowPaneRoot.getChildren().add(title);
    flowPaneRoot.getChildren().addAll(bananaCB,mangoCB,papayaCB,grapfruitCB);
    flowPaneRoot.getChildren().add(response);
    flowPaneRoot.getChildren().add(selected);


    //Attach eventListeners to our checkboxes.


    Scene scene = new Scene(flowPaneRoot,400,250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

public void showAll(){
    fruits = "";
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void handle(Event event) {
    Object fruitSelected = event.getSource();
    if (bananaCB.equals(fruitSelected)) {
        if (bananaCB.isSelected()) {
            response.setText("Banana Selected");
        } else {
            response.setText("Banana cleared");
        }
    }

}
```

}

I did try an setOnAction eventhandler and it worked as expected. I had it commented out in the code above but it messed up the way it looked. I'll post it here.

```
        bananaCB.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
       public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            response.setText("Banana Selected");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your `handle` method is not being called, because you most likely did not attach it anywhere (at least the code you've posted suggests so). Simply implementing an event handler is not enough to attach it, your second snippet is more along the lines of what you should do.

Comment: I was led to believe that this was a kind of catch-all EventHandler that made it so I didn't have to write out 4 different setOnAction handlers. It is catching all the events and then I'm looking to see if the "event" is called bananaCB in the if statement and changing the Label if the event clicked matchs. Am I wrong in my thinking? sorry I'm new to this

Comment: Not sure why you believe this. If you look at what `Application` class looks like and what methods it has, there is nothing related to event handling on there, and that would be the only place where you could have something like this. Otherwise, an `EventHandler` interface describes a listener which is meant to be attached to a specific component, and there is no catch-all semantics attached to it, as JavaFx doesn't really have a notion of a "DeadEvent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could attach the event your application class as event handler to multiple `CheckBox`es, but I wouldn't recommend it. Furthermore you need to actually register the handlers using the `setOnAction` method:

```
bananaCB.setOnAction(this);
mangoCB.setOnAction(this);
...
```

Moreover using the same event handler and checking all possible sources is bad practice.
I'd recommend using `ChangeListener`s for the `selected` properties instead in this case and use different lambdas/anonymus classes for each `CheckBox`:

```
private static CheckBox createFruitCheckBox(final String text) {
    CheckBox result = new CheckBox(text);
    ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                                               response.setText(newValue ? text + " Selected" : text + " cleared");

    result.selectedProperty().addListener(listener);
    return result;
}
```

```
bananaCB = createFruitCheckBox("Banana");
mangoCB = createFruitCheckBox("Mango");
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, I was following an instructional video that didn't have "this" part in it. I am going to incorporate your code into this project. Thanks again for your answer and help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right condition is bananaCB.ischecked.

try it. its possible that the label is not changing because of the wrong method call

Comment: Thanks for the trying to help but it is isSlected() , I checked into that already.  Thanks again